# Duvida com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs

O que tem de errado com esse código? Estou tentando executar ele, mas de forma alguma ele me mostra os dados vindos do banco!

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('clienteController', ['$scope', '$http', clienteController]);

function clienteController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3091/api/ClientesWebAPI/Getcliente')
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.listaclientes = data;

    })
    .error(function () {
      $scope.erro = "Erro: Nao foi possivel carregar.";
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h2>Listagem de Clientes</h2>

<div data-ng-controller="clienteController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Lista de clientes</div>
        <div class="panel-body">


    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>{{erro}}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td>ID</td>
                                <td>Nome</td>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>Idade</td>
                                <td>Data nascimento</td>
                                <td>Data cadastro</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="cliente in listaclientes">
                                <td>{{ cliente.id_nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.idade }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.sexo }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta voce colocar o `ng-app="app"` para o angular iniciar e renderizar na sua página.

Aonde está `<div data-ng-controller="clienteController">`

Deve ficar 
    `<div ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="clienteController">`

Não esqueça de verificar se você colocou as referências para os arquivos do AngularJS na sua pagina.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Abaixo segue um exemplo funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('clienteController', ['$scope', '$http', clienteController]);

function clienteController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3091/api/ClientesWebAPI/Getcliente')
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.listaclientes = data;

    })
    .error(function () {
      $scope.erro = "Erro: Nao foi possivel carregar.";
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h2>Listagem de Clientes</h2>

<div ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="clienteController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Lista de clientes</div>
        <div class="panel-body">


    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>{{erro}}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td>ID</td>
                                <td>Nome</td>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>Idade</td>
                                <td>Data nascimento</td>
                                <td>Data cadastro</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="cliente in listaclientes">
                                <td>{{ cliente.id_nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.idade }}</td>
                                <td>{{ cliente.sexo }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mesmo assim, nada ainda... que foda!

Comment: quando voce clica no executar da minha resposta nao faz nada?
pra mim aqui faz: ele tanta comunir o service que ta rodando na porta 3091 do localhost ... verifica se seu servico esta rodando nessa porta mesmo e se ele esta respondendo.

Comment: verifica tambem se no seu DevTools ... se está dando alguma mensagem de erro quando voce carrega a pagina. Confere se voce fez a referencia para o angular.js , igual foi feito no exemplo que eu postei ...

Comment: agora deu certo. O que estava causando o erro era nada mais nada menos que as bibliotecas
**
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
**

obs: Estou desenvolvendo no visual studio, dai certa dificuldade!! Obrigado André :D

Comment: essas bibliotecas estao na resposta justamente pra que o codigo funcione aqui no site. mas na sua versao, ou voce mantem essa ou declara voce msm... mas se resolveu o seu problema, está valendo!!! o que era no final das contas? de fato faltava o `ng-app`?

Comment: tambem, mais o principal problema era o link das bibliotecas declaradas em cima... não tinha elas auhauhauhauahuah erro de iniciante!!

Comment: Então vou atualizar a resposta e aí vc marca!! Fechou!